# linq dynamic where clause with or condition on a INT column

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm attempting to use a linq query to dynamically select records based on account id.  account id is a int column in sql server.

```
var idList = new int[123, 456];   //these number change with each user.
foreach (var id in idList) {
      query = query.WHERE(cs => cs.pkID = id);
}
```

The above makes it a AND where clause.  I'd rather have it be an OR.
The above idList can contain 1 to 100.  Varying with each user.

How can I make linq work with a OR clause.  Contains doesn't work on INT columns.

Would like the select to look something like this.

```
 select * from table where id = 123 or id = 456
```

I have a bunch of other columns that could be appended to the where clause.  Getting a dynamic OR working is giving me a headache.

Thanks.

Comment: The SQL would use `IN`:  `where id in (123, 456)`.

Comment: i'm using linq to solve this.  please be on point.

Comment: @user3434990 While the link provided as duplicate for this question is very useful, I think using Contains in your case is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cs=>idList.Contains(cs.pkID)`

```
var idList = new List<int>(){123, 456};   
var result = query.Where(cs => idList.Contains(cs.pkID));
```

This way you don't need any loop and it is equivalent to:

```
SELECT somecolumns FROM sometable WHERE pkId in (123, 456)
```

In your case, using Contains, makes more sense than creating dynamic where clause with `OR`.

Comment: Contains is not an option for idList

Comment: @user3434990 it is an option when you use a List.

Comment: i believe you can use `idList.Cast<int>().Contains(cs.pkID)` if you have to use array

Comment: Thanks Reza that worked

Comment: @user3434990 you are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

```
query = query.WHERE(cs => idList.Contains(cs.pkID);
```

You can use something like that.

Watch our with your original query: = is not == in C#.

Comment: as mentioned above idList.Contains is not an option..what I mean is it isn't available in the list of properties.

Comment: Just add a .ToList()?